# I can't load a numpy .npy file that I just saved

Tags: python, numpy

To save a `numpy` array, I'm doing:

```
save_tokens = 'myfile.npy'
token_file = open(save_tokens, 'ab')

tokens = np.array([], dtype='object')
line_count = 0
tokens_to_save = np.array([], dtype='object')
with open(self.corpus_file) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if line_count % 1000 == 0:
            print("Line Count: ", line_count, '')
            if save_tokens is not None:
                np.save(token_file, tokens_to_save)
                tokens_to_save = np.array([], dtype='object')
        line_count += 1
        line_tokens = pygments.lex(line + '\n', self.lexer)
        for line_token in line_tokens:
            tokens = np.append(tokens, line_token[1])
            tokens_to_save = np.append(tokens_to_save, line_token[1])
        if line_count % 10000 == 0:
            print("\tToken Count: ", len(tokens))

np.save(token_file, tokens_to_save)
```

I can confirm that it saves and there's a file called `myfile.npy` that's 1.8MB.

When I try to load and read it:

```
f = open('myfile.npy', 'rb')
self.tokens = np.load(f, allow_pickle=True)
[print(token) for token in self.tokens]
print(self.tokens)
f.close()
return self.tokens
```

I also tried:

```
self.tokens = np.load('myfile.npy', allow_pickle=True)
[print(token) for token in self.tokens]
print(self.tokens)
return self.tokens
```

It prints an empty list `[]`. How can it be empty?

Comment: If you repeatedly `np.save` to a `ab` file, you will save a bunch of arrays.  But `np.load` will only load the first one that you saved, which apparently is a `np.array([])`.

Comment: You shouldn't be making a `np.array([],object)` array and repeatedly `np.append` to it.  Even when it works, it is inefficient.  Use list append to make a list of arrays.  Then form an array from that.  And do only one save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's do several saves to one file:

```
In [92]: ofile = open('test.npy', 'ab')                                                                         
In [93]: np.save(ofile, np.array([], object))                                                                   
In [94]: arr = np.array([], object)                                                                             
In [95]: arr = np.append(arr, np.array([1,2,3]))                                                                
In [96]: arr                                                                                                    
Out[96]: array([1, 2, 3], dtype=object)
In [97]: arr = np.append(arr, np.array([1,2,3]))                                                                
In [98]: arr                                                                                                    
Out[98]: array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], dtype=object)
In [99]: np.save(ofile, arr)                                                                                    
In [100]: np.save(ofile, np.arange(12).reshape(3,4))                                                            
In [101]: ofile.close()
```

Do an ordinary load:

```
In [103]: np.load('test.npy', allow_pickle=True)                                                                
Out[103]: array(['✪'], dtype=object)
```

Looks like I got that original `[]` array, but what's its content?

Instead open the file, and try repeated loads:

```
In [107]: f = open('test.npy', 'rb')                                                                            
In [108]: np.load(f, allow_pickle=True)                                                                         
Out[108]: array(['✪'], dtype=object)             # one 
In [109]: np.load(f, allow_pickle=True)                                                                         
Out[109]: array([], dtype=object)                # two
In [110]: np.load(f, allow_pickle=True)                                                                         
Out[110]: array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], dtype=object)    # three
In [111]: np.load(f, allow_pickle=True)              # four                                                           
Out[111]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [112]: np.load(f, allow_pickle=True)                                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EOFError
```

So yes it is possible to save and load multiple arrays to one file, but that's not how it was intended.  `np.savez` is meant for saving multiple files.  And saving object dtype arrays can be problematic.  Their databuffer has pointers to objects else where in memory.  The pointers are no valid in a save/load sequence.  So instead it has to use pickling.

Comment: Can you possibly update your answer with `savez` so I can see how to continually append to an array (Saved to disk)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to open the file to read or output a `numpy` array using `np.load` and `np.save`.

It should be the following to save:

```
np.save('myfile',tokens_to_save)
```

And then the following to load:

```
self.tokens = np.load('myfile.npy', allow_pickle=True)
```

**Edit**

You can't iteratively save a `numpy` array like this. If you want to do it iteratively save it as a text file. `np.save` will overwrite the file overtime you call it. Consider the example below,

```
np.save('test',np.arange(0,100,10))

np.save('test',np.arange(0,200,10))
p = np.load('test.npy',)

print p
```

The only output when you read it in is `[  0  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100 110 120 130 140 150 160 170 180 190]`

Comment: Same result when I do this

Comment: Im guessing you already tried this, but did you try including an absolute path?

Comment: I'm using the same path as in the `.save`

Comment: Also remove the `open(save_tokens)` for when you save the array.

Comment: I need to keep the `open(save_tokens)` since I'm continually appending

Comment: You can't iteratively save a `numpy` array like that. `np.save` will overwrite the file every time you call `np.save`. This means that your last line would also overwrite everything in your loop.

Comment: If you keep the Path open then yes, so give that a shot and see if that fixes your problem

Comment: Yes you can do multiple saves to a one file, but then you'll have to do multiple loads as well.  This appends to the file, not to the previously saved array. And there's no random access to those arrays either.  For that you should use `savez`.